# IBM HS23 Blade Server (7875) onboard NIC driver for linux

Tags: linux-networking, emulex

I work with IBM HS23 Blade Server (7875). 
It's onboard NIC adapter is:

```
   Emulex OCl11104-F-X Virtual Fabric Adapter 2-port 10GB and 2-port 1GB LOM .
```

I'm tryed to the following Linux OS with the server:

```
2.6.32-22-generic-pae #36-Ubuntu SMP.
```

and discovered my OS has not proper Network drive installed (for the NIC adapter described above). 
After investigation I made, I discovered that the driver I need is "be2net" placed in "net" directory of the linux under the folder "be2net". I managed to download this driver with the latest package for my kernel. Driver info ("modinfo be2net" result) is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.32-22-generic-pae/kernel/drivers/net/benet/be2net.ko
license:        GPL
author:         ServerEngines Corporation
description:    ServerEngines BladeEngine2 10Gbps NICDriver 2.101.205
version:        2.101.205
srcversion:     199ADD251CB874C3727CC47
alias:          pci:v000019A2d00000710sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000019A2d00000701sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000019A2d00000700sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000019A2d00000221sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000019A2d00000211sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        
vermagic:       2.6.32-22-generic-pae SMP mod_unload modversions 586TSC 
parm:           rx_frag_size:Size of a fragment that holds rcvd data. (uint)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After starting linux, I get the following error:

```
be2net 0000:16:00.x: Emulex OneConnect 10Gbps NIC (be3) initilization failed.
```

I checked the same server with another Linux version (Red-Had 5.5.1.0) and the NICs worked properly, so seems there is no problem in HW.

Also, on IBM or Emulex offical sites I managed to find drivers only for Red-Had and SUSE versions.

Answer (score 1):

You need a later version of the be2net driver to support this card.

Try extracting the official drivers, pulling out the source for the be2net driver and building it on your own.